# React Native possible unhandled Promise rejection

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to get values from an API using fetch function of React Native. Then label values retrieved from JSON as Millions , Billions ... etc.

**JSON File**

```
{
  "value": 92060,
  "new": 1
}
```

To Do what I wanted, I used below code.

```
async componentDidMount() {

let data =  await fetch('https://demo614535421.mockable.io/getData')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
    grossRev : this.getCodedValues(responseJson.grossRevenue)
  })

})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
this.setState({ wowData: true });
return data;
```

}

And `getCodedValues()` function,

```
getCodedValues(value)
{
  console.log(Math.abs(Number(value)));
}
```

Before I check millions and billions, iOS simulator started to show an error saying,

```
Undefined is not an Object (evaluating '_reactNative.Math.abs')
```

I used async and await here to hold functions while data are being captured. But still seems like in `getCodedValues` function `value` parameter is `undefined`?

**Problem**

1. How can I solve this and do the arithmetic calculations?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? This only uses async/await and doesn't deal with then/catch because when you use await, it waits for fetch to come back with the response.

```
async componentDidMount() {
   try {
      let response =  await fetch('https://demo614535421.mockable.io/getData');
      let responseJson = response.json();
      this.setState({
         grossRev: this.getCodedValues(responseJson.grossRevenue)
      })
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
}
```

Comment: Definitely. OP originally didn't use async correctly. It was awaiting a promise chain, so the behavior didn't work as expected.